# How to set values in C++ template object?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to create a template class that will allow me to print the contents of an object, however, being new to this, I am struggling to set the values of the data.

If, for example, I have a template that takes two typename parameters, how would I go about setting the values? Must I treat every instance of a template in a similar manner to an array or vector?

```
Pair<int, double> first, second;
```

Obviously `first = 10` does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you treat `first` and `second` as fields of your class, you're doing it wrong. Make sure your Pair class has fields named like this and call them `first.first = 10` and `first.second = ...`.

Answer (score 6):

You create two Pair objects, so you cannot assign 5 to one of them, since 5 is not a Pair.

```
Pair<int, double> first, second; // means that you have TWO pairs!
// it was equal to:
// Pair<int, double> first;
// Pair<int, double> second;

first.first = 5;
first.second = 3.14f;

second.first = 3;
second.second = 7.421f;
```

You probably wanted something like this:

```
Pair<int, double> myPair; // only 1 pair
myPair.first = 5;
myPair.second = 3.14f;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you are using `std::pair` and not writing your own pair class.
other than what has already been answered to you, you must also be familliar with `std::make_pair` which creates a pair *and* deducts the types from the arguments, thus making your code smaller and more readable.

example:

`auto myPair = std::make_pair(4,5.6);`

Comment: I'm not sure if he's using std::pair, - why write `Pair` instead of `pair` then? But who knows...